# JavaScript sem funcionar no HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

Boas,

Preciso de uma pequena ajuda que é o seguinte. 
Fui experimentar este codigo no meu computador numa página HTML e não funciona , mas no fiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/uxrkgfoz/) funciona na perfeição . 
Será que me falta alguma coisa ?

Obrigado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Repara que o jsFiddle tem uma opção que insere o teu código dentro de uma função `onLoad`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso quer dizer que todo o teu código vai ficar dentro de

```
window.onload = function(){
    // aqui
}
```

e faz com que o código só seja corrido **depois** do HTML ter sido lido. O que te acontece agora é que o JavaScript corre e não encontra o HTML que está à procura.

#### Solução:

ou fazes com `window.onload = ...` ou então podes colocar o teu código no final da página, antes do final do body. Assim garantes que o HTML já foi lido quando o JavaScript começar a correr.

```
    ...
    <script>
    // código aqui...
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra sugestão é fazer isso com um evento em lista, exemplo:

```
window.onload = function() { 
    var el = document.getElementById("elementoAlvo"); 
        el.addEventListener("click", escopoProjeto, false); 
}

var escopoProjeto = function () {
 //ação do projeto 
}
```