# É possível obter o valor de uma div?

Tags: javascript, html5

Se na div `valor0` tiver um valor, tem como eu obter este valor em uma variável para soma-la por exemplo??

Neste exemplo temos a div `valor0` com o valor 1, tem como eu manda-la para variável teste?

```js
var teste = document.getElementById("valor0").value;
console.log(teste);
```

```html
<html>
 <div id="valor0"> 1 </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Podes ir buscar o `.textContent` e depois fazer parse para converter em Numero.

```js
var text = document.getElementById("valor0").textContent;
var numero = Number(text);
console.log(typeof text, text, '||', typeof numero, numero);
```

```html
<div id="valor0"> 1 </div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!! @Sergio

Comment: Sergio, perdão incomodar, este jeito já deu certo, porém gostaria de saber para estudar, há outro modo para retornar o valor da div??

Comment: @Sora podes usar i `innerHTML` mas se tiveres HTML vai trazer "lixo" que não precisas. Tiveste problemas com o código da resposta, ou tens HTML diferente?

Comment: Então, é que eu usei este método para pegar o valor de uma div e retornou o erro: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null
    at ...

Comment: Pelo o que eu vi, este erro se dá pelo fato do script não achar a div ou algo do tipo

Comment: @Sora exato. Pode ser um problema parecido com este https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134810/129 Senão aconselho a fazer uma pergunta, ou coloca aqui um jsFiddle com um exemplo que posso ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio !!!!